# Estimating parameters of normal distribution using bootstrap [r]

Tags: normal-distribution, bootstrap

I am trying to run a simulation how to estimate parameters of normal distribution when we do not have many observation. I am using 50 observation-  in most textbook is is said that when we have 30 and more observation cental limit theorem hold.

Here I am using bootstrap to obtain distribution of mean of data as well as standart deviation of data:

```
A <- rnorm(50, 10, 4)

sd(A)
mean(A)

res <- tibble()
for (i in 1:500) {
  message(i)
  res_i <- cbind(mean = 
          sample_n(data.frame(A), size = length(A), replace = T) %>% 
          pull(A) %>% mean(), 
        sd = sample_n(data.frame(A), size = length(A), replace = T) %>% 
          pull(A) %>% sd())
  res <- rbind(res, res_i)  
}

res %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(fill = key))


MASS::fitdistr(res$mean, "normal")
MASS::fitdistr(res$sd, "normal")
```

Is there any better way how to obtain parametr of DGP distibution. Here I am basically saying that DGP normal distibution have mean from normal distribution and sd from normal distribution: N(N(mu1, sd1), N(mu2, sd2)).

Isn't this approach to over-complicated?

Comment: The short answer is yes, this estimation procedure is over-complicated.  The standard methods to estimate Normal parameters are good ones: use the sample mean and bias-corrected sample variance.  Neither requires the CLT.  They work even with samples of size 2.  But are you perhaps asking whether your *simulation approach* is over-complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to conduct a bootstrap to estimate the sampling distribution of the mean and standard deviation. The following R code would suffice:

```
# using dplyr, purrr, and ggplot2 packages from the tidyverse
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

# your data
my_data <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 10, sd = 4)

# desired number of sims
n_simulations <- 1000

# boot strapped means and standard deviations
bootstrapped_means_and_sds <- map_df(.x = 1:n_simulations, 
                                     .f = function(i) {
                                       
                                     bootstrapped_sample <- sample(x = my_data, 
                                            size = length(my_data), 
                                            replace = TRUE) 
                                       
                                     tibble(sample_mean = mean(bootstrapped_sample),
                                            sample_sd = sd(bootstrapped_sample))  
                                       
                                     })

# histogram of the bootstrapped sampling distribution of the mean.
ggplot(data = bootstrapped_means_and_sds, mapping = aes(x = sample_mean)) +
  geom_histogram()

# histogram of the bootstrapped sampling distribution of the sd.
ggplot(data = bootstrapped_means_and_sds, mapping = aes(x = sample_sd)) +
  geom_histogram()

# histogram of the bootstrapped joint sampling distribution of the mean and sd.
ggplot(data = bootstrapped_means_and_sds, mapping = aes(x = sample_mean, y = sample_sd)) +
  geom_point()
```

That being said, if you just want to estimate the mean and standard deviation of your data, then you can use the method of moments (sample mean and bias-corrected sample sd) or maximum likelihood (sample mean and sample sd). If you are looking for a Bayesian approach (where uncertainty in the parameters is described as a probability distribution) you could use the normal-inverse gamma distribution as a conjugate prior.